# Using switchClass with a hover on a parent class to a child class, but not affecting other divs with the same class

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I'm using `.switchClass` on `.container` on a hover state to switch `.child1` from 100% width to 40% width, but I have .container on more than one div. I only want the `.switchClass` function to happen on the one .container i'm hovering on, not all of them, but I don't want to use IDs because I'd rather not have a million scripts for each row I have to create (I need about 30)

So I have a series of rows that have a container then two side-by-side divs, called `child1` and `child2`. In the default (non-hover) state, I want `child1` to span the full width of the container. Then, when you hover over the container, I want `child1` and `child2` to slide over so that `child1` is 40% width and `child2` is auto width. I'm currently using `switchClass` to achieve this.

I have that working, but now my issue is that when I hover on one container, the animation happens to all the divs with the class "container".

Mind you, I have so far taught myself jQuery from googling and StackOverflow, so my understanding is very limited, and I've used very few functions so far. So sorry if this is a very easy problem to fix.

So far, I've found solutions saying to use `$(this)` as the selector, but because I want the class of `child1` to switch when I hover on container, I haven't really figured out how to properly use `$(this)` in that context, because then it tries to switch the class on .container

The only reason I haven't switched to using IDs is because I need about 30 of these rows on this page. I just want to be able to show a little summary of what that image refers to when you hover on it.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sling/d6x4sfLn/

```js
$(function() {
  $(".container").on('click', function() {
    $(".image-card").switchClass("image-card", "image-card-hover", 1000);
    $(".image-card-hover").switchClass("image-card-hover", "image-card", 1000);

  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  .image-h2 {
    color: white;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  }
  .image-card {
    background-image: url("http://www.steves-digicams.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Nikon_D850_Sample_13.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .image-card-hover {
    background-image: url("http://www.steves-digicams.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Nikon_D850_Sample_13.jpg");
    background-image: url("http://www.steves-digicams.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Nikon_D850_Sample_13.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .text-card {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    padding-left: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-bootstrap/0.5pre/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="first">
  <div class="image-card">
    <h2 class="image-h2">
      This is the first project
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-card">
    <h2>
      Title
    </h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin posuere urna non magna imperdiet, non commodo magna finibus. Integer vel lacus sit amet augue imperdiet malesuada. Praesent hendrerit gravida ligula, ac tempor sapien pharetra eget. Maecenas
      hendrerit, odio quis eleifend vehicula, lacus dui pretium urna, quis facilisis tortor augue eget ipsum. Sed viverra massa vitae pretium tristique. Quisque nec felis mi.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="second">

  <div class="image-card">
    <h2 class="image-h2">
      This is the first project
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="text-card">
    <h2>
      Title
    </h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin posuere urna non magna imperdiet, non commodo magna finibus. Integer vel lacus sit amet augue imperdiet malesuada. Praesent hendrerit gravida ligula, ac tempor sapien pharetra eget. Maecenas
      hendrerit, odio quis eleifend vehicula, lacus dui pretium urna, quis facilisis tortor augue eget ipsum. Sed viverra massa vitae pretium tristique. Quisque nec felis mi.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of just the one `.container` I'm hovering on having the effect, all of the `.containers` have the effect.

Comment: I'm not sure why the background image isn't showing up here like in jsfiddle.

Comment: Oh, it's because jsfiddle supports SCSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to select just the elements in the same contain:

```
$(function() {
  $(".container").on('click', function() {
    $(this).find(".image-card").switchClass("image-card", "image-card-hover", 1000);
    $(this).find(".image-card-hover").switchClass("image-card-hover", "image-card", 1000);

  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/fpzts13e/1/)

Comment: Was having issues getting it to work in my index.html file but I figured it out! Sorry for taking away the correct answer checkmark, and thanks for your help!